# No NavigateToPageAction in Silverlight

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0, expression-blend

I cant find the `NavigateToPageAction` in `Silverlight` and i cant even use `HyperlinkAction` because we have a `<frame name="mainFrame">`  and the `TargetWindow` will only have *_blank*, *_parent*, *_self* value [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723914%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

```
xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
     <ec:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/MainPageAppView.xaml"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers
```

any help please or any suggestion..